# IntelliJ Idea compiling with SBT by default

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Let's say I have a `scala` code, opening in `intellij idea`:

```
object Test extends App {
                           // <- I click here
  def init[T](xs: List[T]) : List[T] = xs match {
    case List() => throw new Error("empty list")
    case List(x) => List() // empty list 
    case head :: tail => head :: init(tail)
  }

  val list = List(1,2,4)

  println ( init(list) )

}
```

Then, what I do when want to launch this code, I click between lines where `object` and `def` is defined to let `IDE` know what I want to launch (in this case whole object, because I do not select any method). Click **CTRL+SHIFT+F10** - to run.

It starts.. I see "Test" in my configuration combo-box... But at that exact moment I stop compilation process .. and go to that configuration to change the config ..

What I change: is **"Before launch"** section to make it run with **"sbt:compile"**. I do it because I want to **rely on SBT but not on IDE**.

The question is: **Is there a way to launch/compile in sbt by default in IntellyJ IDEA?**

Comment: I tried Quick Start -> Configure -> Project Defaults -> Run Configurations -> Defaults -> Application and change here to 'sbt', `test:compile`. However, this doesn't seem to have any effect, if I create a new project, defaults revert to IDEA's own 'make'...

Comment: Ok then will consider this as a bug: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115473  will see.

Answer (score 3):

Yup you can do it, but you'll need to make sure this is a valid SBT project. To verify, make sure you can compile and run from SBT on the command line.

1. Install the SBT plugin for Intellij IDEA
2. Open the run configuration for this Test in Run -> Edit Configurations...
3. In the "Before Launch" section remove Make and add the SBT action "Run SBT Action 'compile'"

Now modify your Test code and re-run. You'll see in the status bar that SBT compile is being run before your Test code executes.

**Updated**
To make this the default behavior for all future run configurations, make this change in the Defaults -> Application item in the Edit Configurations... dialog.

Comment: My understanding of the question was whether you can make IDEA choose that action _by default_.

Comment: Exactly, otherwise I need do/re-configure it all the time when I decide to launch not whole project/test set, but one particural function or test.

Answer (score 1):

Let me update this as this still comes up when searching for a solution. The SBT plugin is now depreciated and we can configure building by SBT from the IntelliJ preferences:

Preferences --> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Build Tools --> sbt: Use SBT shell for imports, for builds

See https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2017/03/23/scala-plugin-for-intellij-idea-2017-1-cleaner-ui-sbt-shell-repl-worksheet-akka-support-and-more/ for more details.